# #define usage in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

I need to write such a define in C/C++

```
#define scanf( fscanf(inf,
```

in order to replace each `scanf(` with `fscanf(inf,` literary

But I do not know how...

Thanks

Comment: Just say no to such use of macros.

Comment: @Brian It is more of curiosity than usage ...

Comment: I agree, what's wrong with a ctrl+h?

Comment: @Mattew Does it differ from a compiler to another?!

Comment: @drachenstern ctrl+h is not flexible to change then revert back then change then ...

Comment: @Beta, it's standard C99.  However, there are also various proprietary versions.

Comment: @Betamoo ~ Ah, now we're getting to more requirements. Why didn't you put that in the question initially? So really what you want is probably to just encapsulate that functionality in another function so you can vary it in ONE place. That's what I would do for testing something like this...

Comment: Removed the C tag as the OP is writing C++.

Comment: @DeadMG The question is equally (if not more) relevant in C. The title specifies C as well as C++. If the OP doesn't clearly distinguish, please don't assume that the question is only related to one or the other language. Remember that SO policy is to *respect the OP*. If there is doubt about what is meant with the question (or which languages it relates to) you do *not* just edit it, or its tags, according to your guess. If the OP agrees that it is *only* about C++, not C, remove the C tag. But not until then.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want to use a [Variadic macro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_macro).

In your case, I believe you want:

```
#define scanf(...) fscanf(inf,__VA_ARGS__)
```

Comment: Note that this is not portable.

Comment: @Brian: it's in the C++0x draft and supported by GNU, Intel and Microsoft, so at least on x86 I'd consider it portable enough for most purposes

Comment: It's in the C99 official standard, so it is portable C.

Comment: The question was originally for just C++, later edited to both C/C++. For those of us who use more compilers than the mainstream, and we want our code to be portable now, this isn't an option. Sure, go ahead and use it if all your target compilers support it. I still think it is worth mentioning that it isn't portable for C++ right now. But yes, it is in the C++0x draft standard.

Comment: spelling: it's variadic, not variadric :)

Answer (score 4):

> I need to write such a define in C++

No, you don't. What you really want to do is redirect `stdin`.

```
freopen(inf, "r", stdin);
```

Answer (score 3):

Just write all your code using fscanf, and define the file name with a macro like this:

```
#ifdef USE_SCANF
#define SCANF_FILE(file) stdin
#else
#define SCANF_FILE(file) file
#endif

fscanf(SCANF_FILE(blah), "%d", &a);
```

Answer (score 1):

not possible the way you tried of course.

you have to do things like

```
#define scanf(S, ...) fscanf(inf, S, __VA_ARGS__)
```

See e.g. [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177415(VS.80).aspx)

EDIT: GNU cpp supports variadic macros too; it is VA_ARGS preceded by double underscore and ended with double underscore... I have to study escaping markup here...

Comment: Surround text with backticks to create inline code. It's the best way to write `__VA_ARGS__` in the middle of a paragraph. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can't replace a parenthesis.  If you're using Visual C++, then you can use a variadic macro to accomplish what you want:

```
#define scanf( format, ... ) fscanf( inf, format, __VA_ARGS__ )
```

Other compilers may have a similar facility, but I'm not familiar with them.

Comment: It's standard C99.  §6.10.3.1

Comment: Colour me surprised.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: C99 standard as far as I know.

Comment: The question was for C++, where this is not standard.

Comment: @Brian: but it's in the C++0x draft, so it's reasonable to use it as long as it's supported by your compiler

Comment: gcc and microsoft's compilers have both the extention. Fastly reading forums, it seems Intel compiler has too someway. And wikipedia says Borland compiler too support them. So I suppose we can say all the main compilers have a preprocessor supporting variadic macro.